# RemoteView appwidget trouble

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am in the process of trying to make a remote view contained with in a widget. The idea seems sound all in all but I'm having a bit of difficulty in the code here is what I am having an issue with:

```
RemoteViews RemV = new RemoteViews(getResultData(), R.layout.config);
RemV.addView(appWidgetId, R.id.adView);
```

so far the addview is not letting me register R.id.adView

How can I get around this.

Comment: What type of view represents R.id.adView?

Comment: BTW, your call to RemoteViews.addView won't compile... It's addView(int viewId, RemoteViews nestedView)

Answer (score 0):

Impossible - you can't put adView into widget. Take a look at widgets reference for allowed controls.

Comment: adView is not a control! It's the identifier @CodeMonkeyAlx chose for his view